# applying style to textview drawable

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout for a TextView and drawable as such...

```
<LinearLayout style="@style/dashboard_content_horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        style="@style/dashboard_imageview"
        android:src="@drawable/menu6" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/dashboard_textview"
        android:text="@string/menu6_text />

</LinearLayout>
```

as you can see the image uses a style attribute which looks like this

```
<style name="dashboard_imageview">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">fitCenter</item>
</style>
```

the linear layout's style surrounding it looks like this

```
<style name="dashboard_content_horizontal">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0px</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">3</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

and TextView's style

```
<style name="dashboard_textview">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

this all works and looks exactly how I want it to look.  however, because of this eclipse warning
"This tag and its children can be replaced by one  
and a compound drawable"  I decide to try to do this with just a TextView and drawable

like such..

```
<TextView  
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Menu6" 
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/my_drawable"
    android:padding="5dp" />
```

this renders the image too small..  I don't see a way to apply a style to the image to get it like I want it.. anyone know the answer? is even possible?